# No output for rake spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run some `rspec` tests for my Rails app, and when I type the `rake spec` command nothing happens. There is no output. Below is my Gemfile. What am I doing wrong?

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'test-unit'
    gem 'minitest'
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
    gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
    gem 'simplecov', :require => false
end
```

Comment: If you're using the newer version of RSpec, the command is `rspec`, not `spec`. And drop the `rake`.

Comment: Thanks @ArcaneCraeda - you were right about the newer version and the command worked.

Comment: Does it quit immediately or pause as though it's loading Rails? What's in your test/log file?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use just `rspec` not `rake spec`